# Arizona spider that I cannot identify - help?

Tags: species-identification

I cannot seem to find a "duplicate" photo of this spider anywhere and am curious what it is. It came by to say hello on my back patio in Vail, Arizona so I snapped this shot.
Any input would be amazing so I have more info if I should encounter another.

Thanks!

[image: spider]

Comment: Could well be *Latrodectus* sp. Known as "widow spiders" including  the famous "black widow" Compare with [this photo](https://bugguide.net/node/view/447580), but I'll let someone more knowledgeable ID this one.

Answer (score 5):

It's a subadult female Western Black Widow, Latrodectus hesperus.  The pattern on the back will fade to black when she molts into her final adult growth stage, but the red "hourglass" marking on the underside will be quite visible from an early stage.  Good photo!  You can nicely see the big "mecha" legs that make adult Widows stand out so much from related Theridiid (comb-footed) spiders.  Even young female Widows can deliver a serious (but usually not dangerous) bite, but not all bites deliver a full load of (or even any) venom.  Still, and even considering that these spiders are extremely inoffensive, I wouldn't care to handle one myself.  Accidents happen!
Here's a link and photo:
https://bugguide.net/node/view/1854758

[image]